# Is all RSA encryption now considered insecure? (Notably SSH and SSL)

Tags: tls, ssh, rsa

Some of the leaks which emerged during/after Snowden concerned the fact that the NSA was paying the organization behind RSA a *lot* of money in order for them to systematically weaken the encryption by default.

Since both SSL and SSH typically use public/private RSA keypairs for their encryption, is this encryption now considered insecure?

What exactly was leaked, and does it cast doubts on the security of all SSL/SSH encryption?

Comment: If this is about RSA (the cryptosystem) then this it's too broad _and_ primarily opinion-based (because we can only speculate on what the NSA is _really_ doing). If this is about RSA (the company) then you clearly have no idea what you're asking. The NSA-RSA thing is about their RSA's (the company) PRNGs, and really has nothing to do with SSL/SSH. In any case, we really don't know what the NSA really knows.

Comment: @Adnan Well, you're in trouble if you used RSA-the-company's backdoored and ironically-named BSafe crypto library for SSH or TLS (well, its PRNG, anyway). So it can be related, in a way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are confusing [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29), a family of cryptosystems that relies on the difficulty of factoring products of large prime numbers, with [RSA Security LLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Security), a company which sells security-related products.

RSA and RSA are both called RSA after Messrs [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Rivest), [S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shamir) and [A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Adleman), who both invented the RSA cryptosystem and founded the RSA company. The company was founded in part to market products that rely on the cryptosystem.

The current controversy relates to RSA (the company) allegedly [deliberately weakening one of their products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Security#Alleged_NSA_Dual_EC_DRBG_backdoor) in order to make it easier for NSA to spy or otherwise attack users of these products. This weakening has nothing to do with RSA (the cryptosystem).

If anything, the current revelations of NSA's capabilities strengthen the confidence that we may have in most reputable, widely-used cryptographic algorithms: the Snowden revelations concern ways to bypass cryptographic protections in various ways (by making service providers reveal their secret keys, exploiting software bugs, implanting spying hardware, etc.). If NSA could break cryptographic algorithms, they wouldn't need to go through all this.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to RSA (the cryptosystems invented by Rivest, Shamir, and Adleman) not being equivalent to RSA Data Security (the company also founded by them 5 years *after* RSA was invented), the original creators of the cryptosystem sold their company to Security Dynamics in 1996. By that time, Shamir and Adleman had already left the company, and Rivest had his attention divided between the company and his position at MIT (Massachusetts Institute of Technology). Keep in mind that up until the mid-2000s, the company was not NSA-friendly so the cryptosystems created before that time was unlikely to have been negatively influenced by the NSA.

Here's a quote from an early article from May 1, 1999:

> Although Shamir and Adleman soon ended their affiliation with RSA, Rivest stayed with the company, which was sold to Security Dynamics in 1996 for $250 million. Rivest now divides his attention between RSA and his teaching and administrative duties at MIT.

You can read about RSA Security and its more recent history here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Security

The lengthly entry should prove more useful than any rehash I provide.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing RSA-the-algorithm with RSA-the-company. The company was found to be complicit with the NSA in promoting a compromised pseudorandom number generator. This had nothing to do with the RSA public key encryption algorithm used in SSL/TLS.